# Better way to get next higher or lower Integer from an Integer List

Tags: java

I have a list of Integers (1 to n). Also I am passing an Integer and comparing its value with values of above list. I came up with following. It works fine per my need :

```
public class GetNextPrevious {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        getNextPrevious(11, "getNext", "getPrevious");
        
    }
    
    public static void getNextPrevious (Integer myInt, String getNext, String getPrevious) {
        
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        intList.add(1);intList.add(2);intList.add(3);intList.add(4);intList.add(5); 
        intList.add(6);intList.add(7);intList.add(8);intList.add(9);intList.add(10);
        
        for (int i=0; i<intList.size() ; i++) {
            
             Collections.sort(intList); 
             
             if (intList.contains(myInt)) {
                 
             if (myInt == intList.get(0)) {
                 System.out.println("Supplied " + myInt + " - is the MIN value in the list.");
                 break;
             }
             
             if (myInt == intList.get(intList.size()-1)) {
                 System.out.println("Supplied " + myInt + " - is the MAX value in the list.");
                 break;
             }
             
             if (getNext.length() != 0 && myInt == intList.get(i)) {
                 System.out.println("Next higher value is - " + intList.get(i+1));
             }
             
             if (getPrevious.length() != 0 && myInt == intList.get(i)) {
                 System.out.println("Next lower value is - " + intList.get(i-1));
             }
             
             } else {
                 System.out.println("....Invalid input....");
                 break;
             }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**Question:** Is there a short/smarter way of doing it in Java 1.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `SortedSet` instead of `List`.

First, generate a set from 1 to n

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = IntStream.range(1, n).boxed().collect(
   Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)
);
```

If your input is present in the set, it's either a minimum, a maximum, or in between.

Skip any input which is not in set.

```
if (!set.contains(input)) {
  System.out.println("....Invalid input....");
  return;
}
```

With `first()` and `last()` you check for minimum and maximum.

```
if (input.equals(set.first())) {
   System.out.println(input + " - is MIN");
} else if (input.equals(set.last())) {
   System.out.println(input + " - is MAX");
} else {
```

And you use `tailSet` and `headSet` in order to extract adjacent values.

```
    System.out.println("After  - " + set.tailSet(input, false).first());
    System.out.println("Before - " + set.headSet(input).last());
}
```

Comment: @AjayKumar Use IntStream.rangeClosed for an inclusive range.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method indexOf from List, `returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.`

```
public class GetNextPrevious{

 public static void main(String []args){
    getNextPrevious(5, "getNext", "getPrevious");
 }
 
 public static void getNextPrevious (Integer myInt, String getNext, String getPrevious) {
    
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    intList.add(1);intList.add(2);intList.add(3);intList.add(4);intList.add(5); 
    intList.add(6);intList.add(7);intList.add(8);intList.add(9);intList.add(10);
    
    Collections.sort(intList); 
    
    Integer index = intList.indexOf(myInt); //get the index where the elment is
    
    if(index.equals(-1)){ //-1 means there is no element in the list with that value
        System.out.println("....Invalid input....");
    } else if(index.equals(0)){ //if equals 0 means it's the first element in the list
        System.out.println("Supplied " + myInt + " - is the MIN value in the list.");
    } else if(index.equals(intList.size() - 1)){ //if equals it's size -1 means it's the last element in the lsit
        System.out.println("Supplied " + myInt + " - is the MAX value in the list.");
    } else{ //everything good
        if (getNext.length() != 0) {
             System.out.println("Next higher value is - " + intList.get(index+1));
         }
         
         if (getPrevious.length() != 0) {
             System.out.println("Next lower value is - " + intList.get(index-1));
         }
    }
    
}
}
```